# How to schedule an R Script Cronjob in a linux server?

Tags: linux, r, cron

I am trying to schedule a cronjob to execute an R Script in a linux server. I have achieved to type the commands in the server manually and it works. To do so i have to type the following commands:

1. root@debian:~# cd /home/script2
2. root@debian:/home/script2# Rscript scriptSecos.R

How can i specify a cronjob that will execute the previous commands, once a day?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following cron job will run `Rscript scriptSecos.R` from the path `/home/script2`, once a day, at 0:00 (midnight).

```
0 0 * * * cd /home/script2; Rscript scriptSecos.R >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If you want to save the output of the script to a file, change `>/dev/null` with `>/path/to/file`.

You can copy and paste this cronjob in your crontab file (You can open the file by using command `crontab –e`)

Comment: Thank you! In that string, what is the string ">/dev/null 2>&1" doing?

Comment: `2>&1` : redirects stderr (errors) to stdout (normal output).  `>/dev/null` hides all messages. The `2>&1` expression is useful when you want to save both the errors and normal output to a file. That's way I added it, so it is easy for you to do it if you want.

Comment: I used this string and worked perfectly! Thank you **henfiber**

Comment: I must insist how important it is to first do `cd` to your folder! Because if your script cals anything in this folder it will fail. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following site provides useful reference information for crontab

http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

With your example, the following will run the job at 3 am everyday.

```
00      03      *       *       *       Rscript /home/script2/scriptSecos.R
```

Answer (score 0):

add cron as below.

eg:

```
15 23 * * * Rscript /home/script2/scriptSecos.R  >/dev/null 2>&1
```

you have to mention running script type.Then allow cron logs and check its running or not