# How to trigger Shiny App

Tags: rstudio, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny app, which has a chunk of code to preload required data. This process takes a long time, but it only needs to run once each day.

The problem is the shiny_preload_data() function only gets triggered when the first user access the app and this user has to wait for a long time for the data to be ready.

Is there a way to trigger the shiny_preload_data() before the first user opens a browser to access this app?

In side my server.R function, the code structure looks like this:

```
shiny_preload_data()

shinyServer(function(input, output, clientData, session) {
....
}
```

Comment: Why not move that logic out to a separate process that gets kicked off at midnight?

Comment: But I do not want to have extra data/process  maintenance responsibility.

Comment: That's understandable, but what you're trying to do already falls under the "extra maintenance responsibility" category.  You're much better off separating the logic entirely into a separate job.  That's pretty much the *only* way to do it, unless you want to continue inconveniencing the users

Answer (score 1):

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(10000,session = NULL)

GetData <- function(){
  if(!exists("nextCall")){
    Data <<- mtcars
    # 84600 is + 1 day
    nextCall <<- Sys.time() + 120
  }
  else if (Sys.time() >= nextCall){
    Data <<- iris
    # 84600 is + 1 day
    nextCall <<- Sys.time() + 120
    message(paste0("Next call at: ",nextCall))
  }
  else{
    return()
  }
}

ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(tableOutput("table")))
server <- function(input, output, session){

  observeEvent(autoInvalidate(),{
    GetData()
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    autoInvalidate()
    Data
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

- As pointed out by @Taegost its best if you do that via a separate method using `cron job`, here is some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905934/how-to-schedule-an-r-script-cronjob-in-a-linux-server) how to do it.
- If you want your app to do this lets say every x hours,minutes or daily you can write a function similar to mine. I simply check for file existence and compare the `nextCall` timestamp with the current one
- For demonstration purposes I put the checking, which is the `reactiveTimer` to 10 secs and getting new data every 2 mins